# I want to change the HTML code to Selenium code

Tags: python, html, selenium

Original HTML Code

```
<form id="commentUpdateForm" method="post" data-commentid="">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="hidden" name="point" value="">
            <div class="grade_star">
                <span class="ico_star star_rate">
                    <span class="ico_star inner_star" style="width: 0%;"></span>
                </span>
                <em class="num_rate">0<span class="txt_g">/5</span></em>
                <span class="txt_word">Please rate it</span>
            </div>
            <div class="write_review">
                <label for="tfReview" class="lab_review">What did you like about this place?</label>
                <textarea name="contents" id="tfReview2" class="tf_review"></textarea>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

If I click 3 out of 5 points, the HTML code will be changed like this.

```
<form id="commentUpdateForm" method="post" data-commentid="">
        <fieldset>
            *<input type="hidden" name="point" value="3">*
            <div class="grade_star">
                <span class="ico_star star_rate">
                    *<span class="ico_star inner_star" style="width: 60%;"></span>*
                </span>
                <em class="num_rate">0<span class="txt_g">/5</span></em>
                <span class="txt_word">Normal</span>
            </div>
            <div class="write_review">
                <label for="tfReview" class="lab_review">What did you like about this place?</label>
                <textarea name="contents" id="tfReview2" class="tf_review"></textarea>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

So what I want to do is to make it possible to modify it with Python Selenium code for points, but I don't know.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can locate the element with selenium webdriver and modify its value attribute like that:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@id="commentUpdateForm"]//input[name="point"]')
element.setAttribute("value", "3")
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="commentUpdateForm"]//input[name="point"]"}

Comment: Maybe your page is not fully loaded.
Try to do something like `import time` and then `time.sleep(2)` before you search for the element